# Getting Started with JavaScript Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm struggling to understand Promises.

I want to convert the following code to use Promise object(s).

```
function callback1(asyncResult) {  
    var values = asyncResult.getReturnValue();  // returns an array
    doSomething(values); 
};

function getValues(qtyRows, qtyColumns) {
    //someObject definition here.. but not shown for brevity
    var values =  someObject.getValuesAsync(function (asyncResult) { callback1(asyncResult); });   
}
```

I want to convert it to the promise pattern so that I can make the getValues function "then-able", something like this:

```
getValues.then(doSomething);
```

I can't modify the implementation of "someObject" - it's part of an API that I'm constrained.

Comment: I searched for `javascript Promises 101` and found lots of tutorials

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValues(qtyRows, qtyColumns) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    someObject.getValuesAsync(resolve);
  });
}

getValues(qtyRows, qtyColumns)
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```